# Is there a Mailing Report that Groups Link Click Counts

Tags: civimail, civireport, reports

I want to be able to create a report that shows the most clicked links for emails of a certain campaign over a period of time.

As simple as URL, Unique Clicks, Clicks

I know I can do that on a per email basis, but I am trying to do this as part of a larger report that displays the most clicked links per quarter.

Comment: I'd also find this valuable, but I don't think it exists. It seems like you might be able to get close with Mailing Clickthrough Report with Group by URL, but that doesn't seem to work.
I think the path to something like this being available would be to get mailing clickthroughs (and other mailing results) added to api4, then this could be done via Search Kit.